# How to immediate yield a Try inside for Comprehension?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am wondering how can I immediately terminate the for comprehension without calling `Future.failed` and yield the `Try[Failure]` result instead.

Example:

```
for {
    resultOne <- Future {  Successful("Data")  }
    resultTwo <- Future {
         // Something went wrong here...
         // Instead of calling Future.failed(); 
         // I want to terminate this for-comprehension and return a 
         // Failure() object and bypass the next line
    }
    resultThree <- Future {
         // Something went wrong here...
         // Instead of calling Future.failed(); 
         // I want to terminate this for-comprehension and return a 
         // Failure() object and bypass the next line
    }
    resultFour <- Future {
         // ... Some database call which retuns a Try[]
    }
} yield resultFour
```

Another example

You're right in saying that my example is not running in parallel. I guess I don't have other options but to make it like this?

```
for {
    resultOne <- Future {  Successful("Data")  }
    resultFour <- {
         // ... Some async function which returns a Try 
       }
       .flatMap {
           case Success(resultTwo) => // ... Some async function which returns a Try 
           case Failure(ex) => Future.success(Failure(ex))
       }
       .flatMap {
           case Success(resultTwo) => // ... Some database call which retuns a Try[]
           case Failure(ex) => Future.success(Failure(ex))
       }
    }
} yield resultFour
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there has this fail-fast behaviour but is not running in parallel! You need to create the Futures outside the comprehension in order to run them in parallel.

There is no comprehension behind the scenes, it is syntactic sugar over map/flatMap. So it is not a "thing" you can cancel as a whole.

I assume what you want is to stop other futures if one fails (e.g. to save resources or return as soon as anything fails). Scala's Futures don't support this. [Monix](https://monix.io/) is a scala library that provides  `CanceleableFuture` that supports exactly this use case.

Comment: I guess I don't have a choice. I've updated my post and added another example.